# Есть ли в Windows Forms элемент похожий на <div>?

Tags: c#, winforms

Нужно отобразить картинку и текст в форме [Img][text]. Также нужно чтобы эта конструкция вела себя как один элемент, так как на OnClick должна реагировать.
Картинка имеет фиксированный размер 48х48 пикселей. Кроме того, это все нужно вывести списком в два столбца. Какой элемент можно использовать для таких группировок?

Comment: для картинок `PictureBox`. А список можно организовать массой различных  способов, пробуйте и выбирайте.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можете использовать `UserControl`. На него можно кидать другие элементы управления и повторно использовать. Более того, он для этого и создан.